# Как связать данные в БД и ExpandableListView

Tags: java, android, sqlite

У меня есть БД `SQLite` и есть метод, который считывает данные из таблицы, и отдает массив. У меня сейчас в таблице 1800 записей и этот метод работает очень медленно. Можно ли его как-то оптимизировать?

```
public static ArrayList <String>  checkStoreWorks(Context context){
        ArrayList <String> docTypes = new ArrayList<>();
        SQLiteDatabase db = DBH.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
        Cursor c = db.query(DBH.Storeworks.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
        if (c.moveToFirst()) {
            int nameColIndexO = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.Storeworks.DC.NAME);
            do {
                docTypes.add(c.getString(nameColIndexO));
                Log.d("StoreWorks!!!",
                                ", NAME = " + c.getString(nameColIndexO)
                );

            } while (c.moveToNext());
        } else
            Log.d("Nothing in DB", "0 rows");
        c.close();
        return docTypes;
    }
```

Comment: а для чего тебе могут понадобиться сразу все 1800 записей? может лучше частями подгружать?

Comment: данные подгружаются в выпадающий список, где пользователь, может выбрать одну из позиций. Может и есть смысл подгружать частями, но не получится ли проблемы, что человек скролит список, а данные еще не успели подгрузится? или погрузились не все.

Comment: И если частями подгружать, то как их правильно делить?

Comment: для начала я бы просто убрал бы логированние внутри цикла. Это очень сильно грузит. Но лучше использовать адаптеры, которые умеют работать с базой. Они ве сделают самостоятельно.

Comment: @KoVadim вы имеете ввиду SimpleCursorAdapter?

Comment: да, копайте в этом направлении.

Comment: Полученный при запросе Cursor наиболее оптимально работает с адаптером (CursorAdapter) и выводом в список, не рекомендуется при работе с БД делать промежуточные перемещения в какие-то массивы, коллекции и т.п. во избежании проблем с оптимизацией

Comment: Адаптеры это прекрасно. Но в какой контрол происходит загрузка записей. Именно контрол принимает решение о том, что в нем произошел скроллинг и надо догрузить следующую партию.

Comment: загрузка пикселей? это интересно.

Comment: Дайте схему таблицы, чистый sql и его EXPLAIN, тогда и поговорим.

Comment: @KoVadim Как правильно переписать используя CursorAdapter, данные из БД мне нужны, в ExpandableListView для children. В адаптере ExpandableListView, создавать еще CusrsorAdapter?

Comment: А вот это я уже не подскажу. Я не так много пишу на андроиде.

Comment: Есть SimpleCursorTreeAdapter, [специально](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/112-urok-53-simplecursortreeadapter-primer-ispolzovanija.html) для ExpandableListView. Обратите внимание, что адаптер читает данные по мере необходимости, а не все сразу, что исключает задержки в работе.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

При работе с данными, хранящимися в БД, не рекомендуется делать дополнительные копирования в какие то коллекции, массивы и тп., так как это может занимать достаточно много времени при определенном количестве данных. Рекомендуется работать напрямую с `Cursor` и соответствующими адаптерами.

Для связи данных в БД с `ExpanadableListView` имеется класс-адаптер [`SimpleCursorTreeAdapter`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/SimpleCursorTreeAdapter.html), одной из особенностей которого является выборка данных по мере надобности (раскрытия пунктов списка), что положительно сказывается на производительности.

Для работы с этим адаптером понадобится организация определенной структуры БД, состоящая из двух таблиц: таблицы с заголовками пунктов (группы) и таблицы с содержимым для раскрывающегося списка, связанные с заголовками их ID (подпункты одной группы промаркированы ID этой группы).

Адаптер выводит список, состоящий из пунктов первой таблицы, как обычный `SimpleCursorAdapter`, так же при реализации адаптера необходимо реализовать метод `getChildrenCursor()`, который будет осуществлять запрос для выборки данных раскрывающейся части списка (из второй таблицы по ID группы). Смотрите [пример реализации](http://startandroid.ru/ru/uroki/vse-uroki-spiskom/112-urok-53-simplecursortreeadapter-primer-ispolzovanija.html).

Так же вы можете использовать класс `CursorLoader` для большей оптимизации за счет асинхронных запросов в БД. Данный класс так же берет на себя обязанности по управлению курсором (не требуется самостоятельно его закрывать при ненадобности или восстанавливать при сменах состояния и др). [Пример реализации](http://www.truiton.com/2014/05/android-simplecursortreeadapter-cursorloader-expandablelistview/) с `CursorLoader`.

PS: хочу отметить, что работа с SQLite в Android реализована достаточно громоздко и "многострочно", а составление и обработка запросов вызывает много трудностей, я бы рекомендовал использовать вместо SQL, базы данных на основе ORM, лучшей из которых считаю [Realm](https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/). Это позволяет работать с более понятными сущностями, как POJO-объекты, количество кода существенно сократится, а CRUD-операции будут более Java-подобные.

Answer (score -1):

Попробуйте Ваш код заменить на этот:

```
String[] docTypes = new String[COUNT_OF_TABLES];
Cursor c = null;
int nameColIndexO = -1;

public static ArrayList<String> checkStoreWorks(Context context) {
    SQLiteDatabase db = DBH.getInstance(context).getWritableDatabase();
    c = db.query(DBH.Storeworks.TABLE_NAME, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    if (c.moveToFirst()) {
        nameColIndexO = c.getColumnIndex(DBH.Storeworks.DC.NAME);
        Integer i1 = 0;
        while (c.moveToNext()) {
            new Thread(new i1(i1)).start();
            i1++;
        };
    } else {
        Log.d("Nothing in DB", "0 rows");
    }
    c.close();
    return docTypes;
}

private class i1 implements Runnable {

    private Integer i1;

    i1(Integer i1) {
        this.i1 = i1;
    }

    @Override
    public void run() {
        docTypes[this.i1] = c.getString(nameColIndexO);
        Log.d("StoreWorks!!!", ", NAME = " + c.getString(nameColIndexO));
        return;
    }

}
```

и теперь засеките время, насколько быстрее.

Если вам изначально неизвестно количество таблиц (переменная `COUNT_OF_TABLES`), то можете сделать запрос на количество таблиц.

Comment: я правильно помнимаю, что Вы предлагаете запускать по потоку на каждое добавление в ArrayList? и вроде как ArrayList не threadsafe.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну пускай попробует. Если порядок не устроит, то можно ArrayList заменить на String[] и создать вторую переменную int, которую передавать в Thread.. в общем сейчас изменю вопрос, действительно.

Comment: этот код не нужно даже пробовать. запускать тысячи тредов - это никаких ресурсов не хватит.

Comment: @L'Esperanza если запустить ваш вариант, то получаю android.database.CursorIndexOutOfBoundsException

Comment: @Lucky_girl, теперь попробуйте.

Comment: @KoVadim, как же не хватит то, когда я хоть десятки тысяч Thread у себя одновременно запустить для какого-либо кода.

Comment: Не стоит давать ответы в качестве которых есть сомнения. "Ну пускай попробует .." - это не решение проблемы. Данное решение никак нельзя считать сколько-нибудь приемлемым, не стоит его развивать и что то еще пробовать.

Comment: @pavloff, ясно. Ответ изменил уже.

Comment: Запускать десятки тредов в данном случае лишено любого смысла (ну кроме академического). Прироста производительности не будет. Я боюсь, что сам цикл, который создает такое кол-во тредов будет работать медленее, чем просто добавлять в список. 

А вот использование `i1` для трех различных сущностей в коде... так нельзя.

Comment: @KoVadim, почему `i1` использовать нельзя? Я, вообще, предложил свой вариант - как бы я решил эту проблему. Ну, может быть и есть другие варианты.. но какие? Не знаю.

Comment: можно использовать i1. Просто у Вас и переменная i1, и класс i1, и поле в ней с именем i1. @L'Esperanza Вы плохо решаете задачу. Ваш код ужасен.

Comment: @KoVadim, ну ничего себе, из-за названия переменной код ужасен? Ну новичок может и не поймёт. Два года без перерывов на Java программирую, не так то и много, однако понимаю. Предлагайте своё решение, раз моё не нравится.

Comment: @KoVadim, Вам красота кода нужна или результат? Задача решена нормально.

Comment: не оправдывайте плохой код необходимостью результата.

Comment: @KoVadim, плохой код? Мне не о чём здесь с вами разговаривать.

Comment: Это не решение, а объективно - адский костыль.  С БД вообще так крайне не рекомендуется работать (промежуточные массивы). Для задачи есть [правильное решение](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/560615/%d0%a3%d1%81%d0%ba%d0%be%d1%80%d0%b8%d1%82%d1%8c-%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%b1%d0%be%d1%82%d1%83-%d1%81-%d0%91%d0%94#comment728607_560615). Не нужно так агрессивно реагировать, все мы много не знаем, лучше запомнить на будущее что то новое в решениях

Comment: @KoVadim, ставить минусы из-за принципа - глупо. Название переменной не имеет значения. Браво.

Comment: @pavlofff, видел я этот комментарий и читал статью. Согласен с тем, что решение хорошее. А мой код нормальный.

Comment: Использовать i1 - Ваше право. Это только немного усложняет понимание кода. А вот бессмысленное создание тысяч потоков - вот это плохо. Накладные расходы на создания потока не должны быть больше кода, который в нем исполняется.