# Вопрос по ExpandableListView

Tags: android

У меня есть головная таблица category с полями name и _id. Есть вторая таблица bluda с полями name, _id, categoryID, region, regionID. Есть два активити RusKitchen и ZarKitchen. При открытии RusKitchen необходимо, чтобы показывались только соответствующие категории, и при открытии ZarKitchen тоже самое.

Вот мой код DBHelper

```
public class DBHeler extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
    private static String DB_PATH;
    private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "kitchen.db";
    private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 1;
    public SQLiteDatabase database;
    private Context myContext;

    public DBHeler(Context context) {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        this.myContext = context;
        try {
            DB_PATH = myContext.getDatabasePath(DATABASE_NAME).toString();
            createDataBase();
            openDataBase();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    public Cursor getSingleBludo(long id) {
        return database.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_BLUDA, null, Contract.Entry._ID + " = "
                + id, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getFavoritesBludo() {
        return database.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_BLUDA, null, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_FAVORITE + " = 1",
                null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getCategory() {
        return database.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_CATEGORY, null, null, null, null, null, null);
    }

    public Cursor getBluda(long categoryID) {
        return database.query(Contract.Entry.TABLE_BLUDA, null, Contract.Entry.COLUMN_CATEGORYID + " = "
                + categoryID, null, null, null, null);
    }

    ...
}
```

Адаптер

```
public class ExpListAdapter extends SimpleCursorTreeAdapter {

    DBHeler dbHeler;
    private int layoutChild;
    private int layoutGroup;

    public ExpListAdapter(Context context, Cursor cursor, int groupLayout, String[] groupFrom, int[] groupTo, int childLayout, String[] childFrom, int[] childTo) {
        super(context, cursor, groupLayout, groupFrom, groupTo, childLayout, childFrom, childTo);
        dbHeler = new DBHeler(context);
        layoutChild = childLayout;
        layoutGroup = groupLayout;
    }

    public static class ViewHolder {
        public CircleImageView imgView;
        public TextView txtName;
        public TextView txtIngredients;
        public TextView txtCategory;
        public ImageView imgIcon;

        public ViewHolder(View view) {
            imgView = (CircleImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgView);
            txtName = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtName);
            txtIngredients = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtIngredients);
            txtCategory = (TextView) view.findViewById(R.id.txtCategory);
            imgIcon = (ImageView) view.findViewById(R.id.imgIcon);
        }
    }

    @Override
    protected Cursor getChildrenCursor(Cursor groupCursor) {
        int idColumn = groupCursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry._ID);
        return dbHeler.getBluda(groupCursor.getInt(idColumn));
    }

    @Override
    public Cursor getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return super.getGroup(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public View newGroupView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutGroup, parent, false); // разметка групп
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindGroupView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isExpanded) {

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();
        String category = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME));

        SpannableString strCategory = new SpannableString(category);
        strCategory.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(context, "lobster.ttf"), 0, strCategory.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        holder.txtCategory.setText(strCategory);

        if (isExpanded){
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_up_drop_arrow); //если нажать на группу и раскрыть список
        }
        else{
            holder.imgIcon.setImageResource(R.drawable.ic_right_drop_arrow); //если нажать на группу и скрыть список
        }
    }

    @Override
    public View newChildView(Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild, ViewGroup parent) {
        LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater) context.getSystemService(context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        View view = inflater.inflate(layoutChild, parent, false); // разметка вложенных
        ViewHolder viewHolder = new ViewHolder(view);
        view.setTag(viewHolder);
        return view;
    }

    @Override
    protected void bindChildView(View view, Context context, Cursor cursor, boolean isLastChild) {

        ViewHolder holder = (ViewHolder) view.getTag();

        int _ID = cursor.getInt(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry._ID));
        String name = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_NAME));
        String ingredients = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_INGREDIENTS));
        ingredients = ingredients.replace("\\n", "");
        String image = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(Contract.Entry.COLUMN_ICONS));

        SpannableString strName = new SpannableString(name);
        strName.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(context, "lobster.ttf"), 0, strName.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        SpannableString strIngredients = new SpannableString(ingredients);
        strIngredients.setSpan(new TypefaceSpan(context, "lobster.ttf"), 0, strIngredients.length(), Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);

        holder.txtName.setText(strName);
        holder.txtIngredients.setText(strIngredients);

        Resources resources = context.getResources();
        int resId = resources.getIdentifier(image, "raw", context.getPackageName());
        holder.imgView.setImageResource(resId);
    }
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Делаете выборку по regionID и все, в чем именно проблема? Причем здесь ExpandableListView в заголовке, если проблема с выборкой данных?

Comment: Если я по regionID сделаю выборку, я так понимаю то у меня будет список типа 

Русская кухня и список блюд, Заруб кухня и список блюд. А я хочу чтобы было так: Открывается активити к примеру русская кухня и идет список категорий, раскрываем категории и список блюд.. То же самое и со вторым активити

Comment: Если у вас проблема, как распределить в этот виджет данные, то тут важна структура БД и вам понадобится несколько запросов. Один на извлечение заголовков, другой на соответствующих им пунктов. Посмотрите [этот ответ](http://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/560924/177345)

Comment: Прошелся я по этому ответу. Я в принципе знаю что должны быть две таблицы. Одна для групп, вторая для содержимого этих подгрупп и они должны быть связаны по полю id к примеру. Может для моей задачи есть альтернатива ExpandableListView? Грубо говоря мне бы хотелось чтобы при открытии активити появлялся список типа ExpandableListView, в котором есть только данные для этого активити.

Comment: Есть конечно вариант создать несколько адаптеров для русской и зарубежной кухни, но как-то костляво мне кажется это :)

Comment: да нет, ExpandableListView для этого подходит. Дело только в организации данных и правильных запросах в БД. Головной таблицей должна быть таблица категорий, связанной с ней - таблица блюд. Вторая таблица должна иметь дополнительное поле региона. Первая таблица, тоже, .но только в том случае, если категории разных регионов различаются.  При запросе заголовков (категорий) делаете выборку из первой таблицы  (с фильтрацией по нужному региону, если есть различия в категориях регионов). При выборке пунктов для региона делаете выборку из второй таблицы по ID категории и  по ID региона одновременно.

Comment: сейчас обновлю свой вопрос и выложу что есть у меня

Comment: У меня нет возможности проверять SQL/ Пишите запросы вида `... WHERE id = 1 AND region = 1 ..` регион подставляете динамически в зависимости от того, с какой активити запущено

Comment: да, как раз сейчас переделал метод для выборки категорий, где регион динамически будет ставиться. Проверять буду сейчас

Comment: И все-таки у меня проблема с организацией данных. Я не пойму как занести данные в таблицу category. В вопрос вложил скрины моих таблиц. Как в таблице категорий добавить колонку для региона не понял

Comment: там лишь кусок из таблицы блюда. А категории все перечислены

Comment: нет, структура неправильная. В разных регионах могут быть одинаковые категории, а могут быть и индивидуальные?

Comment: Да, могут быть и разные. Т.е. эти категории в некоторых регионах могут и не быть

Answer (score 0):

таблица категорий - *category*:

```
_id | название | regsID
----------------------
1  | из мяса  | 1
2  | десерт   | 4
3  | напитки  | 5
4  | закуски  | 2
```

regsID = 4 значит, что данная категория входит в 1 и во 2 регион, а regsID = 5, что в 1, 2 и 3 регион (смотрите таблицу regs ниже)

таблица регионов - *region*:

```
_id | name 
---------------
1  | русская  
2  | японская 
3  | современная
```

таблица  - *regs* (таблица для связи многие ко многим, так как категория может быть в нескольких регионах):

```
regionID | regsID
------------------
1       | 1
2       | 2
3       | 3
1       | 4
2       | 4
1       | 5
2       | 5
3       | 5
```

Здесь regsID = 4 указывает, что такая запись входит и в первый и во второй регион, а regsID = 5, что в регионы 1, 2, 3. Аналогично можно указать любые комбинации, в левом столбце перечисляя id из таблицы регионов, а справа указывая одинаковый regsID для каждой комбинации.

таблица блюд - *dish*:

```
_id | name2 | categoryID   | regsID
-----------------------------------------
1  | котлета  | 1            | 1
2  | суши     | 4            | 2
3  | компот   | 3            | 5
4  | пряники  | 2            | 4
5  | бутерброд| 4            | 3
```

компот относится к русской, японской и современной кухне,  пряники - к русской и японской

теперь запросы:

получить категории русской кухни (в таблице region  `_id = 1`, получаем выборку через связь многие ко многим - таблицу *regs*):

```
SELECT _id, name FROM category, regs WHERE regs.regionID = 1 AND category.regsID = regs.regsID
```

получить напитки японской кухни (в таблице category `_id = 3`, в таблице region  `_id  = 2`, тоже через таблицу *regs*):

```
SELECT  dish._id, name2 FROM category, dish, regs WHERE category._id = 3 AND dish.categoryID = category._id AND regs.regionID = 2 AND dish.regsID = regs.regsID
```

Естественно _id во всех запросах нужно подставлять динамически, в первом случае в зависимости от активити с кухней, во втором - первый _id будет позицией адаптера для вложенных в категорию пунктов, второй _id - в зависимости от активити кухни.

**UPD**:
В принципе, я думаю, что в таблице блюд (таблица *dish*) не нужно обращение к регионам через связь многие ко многим, так как один и тот же рецепт вряд ли будет и в русской и в японской кухне одновременно. Если это так и каждое блюдо соответствует только одной кухне, то запрос пунктов для категории можно несколько сократить, указывая в таблице *dish* в поле regsID вместо ID из таблицы связи *regs* напрямую ID из таблицы *region*  и соответственно упростив запрос:

```
SELECT  dish._id, name2 FROM category, dish WHERE category._id = 3 AND dish.categoryID = category._id AND dish.regsID = 2
```

Comment: Запутался я :). Объясните пожалуйста. Сначала я заполнил таблицу regs. В колонке regsID указал категории, а в колонке regionID регионы, к которым данные категории относятся. Дальше запутался и не пойму как заполнить колонку regsID в таблице category

Comment: Я правильно понимаю что в таблице regs поле regsID - это id категории из таблицы category?

Comment: regsID - это не ID категорий , это промежуточная колонка для связи многие ко многим. Так как одна и та же категория может быть в нескольких регионах приходится вводить такую. Здесь перечисляются комбинации с соответствиями между категориями и регионами, каждое новое значение regsID - новая комбинация. Например, regsID = 4 соответствует комбинации, что помеченная таким ID категория входит в русскую и японскую кухню (в колонке regsID значение 4 указано два раза, напротив региона 1 и региона 2) .

Comment: Теперь в таблице *category* в поле regsID для всех категорий, которые входят в регионы русский и японский одновременно, нужно указать  значение 4.