# Как связать таблицы между собой?

Tags: java, sql, android-studio, sqlite, android-sqlite

Пишу проект для андроид устройств и появилась необходимость в использовании баз данных.
Имеется бд в которой 3 таблицы:

1)Таблица "Справочник_продуктов"
-ИД_продукта
-Наименование_продукта

2)Таблица "Справочник_блюд"
-ИД_блюда
-Наименование_блюда

3)Таблица "Справочник_рецептов"
-ИД_Блюда
-ИД_продукта

А теперь к вопросам:
Допустил ли я какие либо ошибки при составлении бд?
Т.к в sql я мало чего понимаю - как мне связать эти таблицы между собой?

Comment: Ну если не считать того, что в схеме отсутствуют количества продуктов - то более-менее. А связывать - по ID-ам.

Comment: @Akina Точно, я совсем забыл про количество. Хотелось бы еще узнать какие команды отвечают за объединение в sqlite?

Comment: вам нужно что-то узнать о связи "многие ко многим" (many to many) видимо. Ранее я вам уже советовал почитать книгу, ее все еще желательно почитать, если хотите понимать больше, чем "мало чего" - там все такие вопросы подробно разбираются и объясняются. Задавая подобные вопросы здесь, вы не начнете понимать в СУБД больше, чем сейчас

Comment: пример базы данных с [связями между ними](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/685470/177345)

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо, просто знаете как это бывает: хочется все и сразу, а еще и быстро

Comment: Поверьте, ее стоит прочитать, прежде чем браться за работу с реляционными БД, в любом случае с БД и SQL быстро не получится, а чем меньше вы знаете о дисциплине, тем медленее будете продвигаться, предмет интуитивно совершенно не понятный. Насчет вашего вопроса - вы уже связали таблицы между собой третьей таблицей, на самом деле вопрос видимо в том, как делать выборки из БД, чтобы получать нужные данные?

Comment: вот еще мой [ответ по связям многие ко многим](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/642915/177345), запросам к БД и даже по блюдам. В принципе его вам должно быть достаточно, больше в формате этого ресурса не напишешь

Comment: @pavlofff Еще кое-что . Разве здесь отношение не многие к одному?Ведь Справочник_продуктов и Справочник_блюд относятся к одной таблице - Справочник_рецептов?

Comment: справочник рецептов многие ко многим, две другие -один к одному, третья связывает первые две

Comment: многие ко многим значит, что одной записи первой таблицы могут соответствовать несколько записей второй и одновременно одной записи второй - несколько из первой. такая связь организуется через служебную таблицу (у вас третья таблица), в отличие от связей один к однтму и один ко многим, где третья таблица не нужна

Comment: @pavlofff Спасибо, теперь стало понятнее.